# Redis driver seems locked when loaded by codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter in one of my PHP project and I noticed that for some transaction I get some kind of lock that seems to occur when the redis driver is loaded.

This does not occur on any transaction and also it seems that if another transaction occur it releases the hanging one.

Did anyone encounter such behavoiur?
[image: profile trace of PHP application]

Comment: What's your current php version ?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.6.2

Comment: we've experienced the same issue lately but we are not sure about the problem behind of that - we changed the redis driver back to files and it looks like the problem was solved; however we used @first redis 2.8.x or something like that and made an upgrade to 3.2. a couple weeks ago alongside from php 5.6. to php 7 - so we coudn't really narrow down the problem - that was the reason behind my question above.
So the question now is - whats your redis version and your ci version ? ;)